# Android Q and back button (Conceptual Question)

Tags: android, android-10.0

With Android Q it seems the back button is gone.
In my app the backbutton is essential to navigating.

Do I need to implement my own button for Android Q and above?

Old devices looks like this. There is the hardware button:

[image]

New devices looks like this:

[image]

New with Android Q you don't have it. You need to swipe from right to left at the very right. Lots of users don't like that and lots of users from old generation will just not use an app, which they see as buggy. A User needs to confugre a special gesture to get back the button and you still don't see it.
We cannot force the user to do any special configuration to get back the button.

So my question is. Should all apps, which depending on this back-button as it was before implement an own back button?

updated question:
Thanks for mentoining appthemes. But still don't get it. My teststyle looks like this. What should I change now to get back the backbutton?

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.BackbuttonTest" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: back  button is not gone anywhere . can u add some more details to your question ? it might have to do something with your theme ..

Comment: If you mean system BACK navigation, whether that is handed by an on-screen button or a gesture is configurable by users on newer versions of Android. However, one way or another, system BACK navigation will exist. But, I agree with ADM: your question needs a lot more detail.

Comment: You need to manage the back button according to your app theme.

Comment: Suppose your App theme contains "NoActionBar" then you need to manage custom back button.